# How do I install Homebrew on Tiger?

Tags: homebrew, macos

According to [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15097/what-is-the-best-hombrew-version-for-an-ibook-running-tiger), I want to install Homebrew Tiger branch on my iBook running ... well, Tiger.
Unfortunatly, when running the Ruby one-liner,

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731/39fc1416e34b9f6db201b4a026181f4ceb7cfa74)"
```

I always get the following error :

```
This script requires the user nicolas to be in the staff group. If this
sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or
however
you please; please refer to the website. If you still want to use this 
script
the following command should work:

dscl /Local/Default -append /Groups/staff GroupMembership $USER
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to add myself as a member of the `staff` group.

What can I do to install Homebrew on my Tiger mac ?

Thanks

**EDIT** Yes, I have a version of XCode for my platform, it's a legacy 2.5 that I installed specifically for that purpose.

Concerning the Ruby script, a rapid overview of its code indicates that the error appears as invoking `groups` does not return the staff group.

And indeed, when I issue this command by hand, I get

```
$ groups
nicolas appserveradm appserverusr admin
```

So, how can I add myself to the `staff` group in a fashion that this command will understand ?

Comment: Can you even obtain a copy of Xcode that will run on your system?

Comment: I would like to get the Tiger Homebrew, but the links below are no longer working. Can someone update a post or provide a new answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew)**: homebrew forked for Tiger PPC

Tigerbrew incorporates work from sceaga's Tiger branch. It installs under the admin group, so you don't have to add yourself to the staff group.

**Installation**:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/go)"
```

And here is a link for downloading Xcode:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally managed to have a working version of homebrew, but it wasn't that simple.

First, download from sources and make install of Git following [these instructions](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-git-on-snow-leopard/).

Then, using git, get [the sceaga Tiger branch](https://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger) of Homebrew.

All should then work correctly (more or less).

**EDIT** There seems to be [a tarball](https://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tarball/tiger) hidden somwhere that could be used with root installation procedure. It has the obvious interest of avoiding one to install git just for the sake of having a running homebrew to ... install another git version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the single-step install of Homebrew on Tiger PPC:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLk https://raw.github.com/gist/1144389/5723f23d03c49912ffd460d32e958e71d7e0cd67/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

It installs sceaga's Tiger branch, precisely the one you quote above…
I've just forked the former install_homebrew.rb and modified it in order to work under Tiger PPC.
You can review [my code here](https://gist.github.com/1144389)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't Tiger, so something only from my memory:

the above dscl should work. Or you can try the following:

```
dscl . -append /Groups/staff GroupMembership $USER
```

you can ensure who is added with

```
echo $USER
```

should print your short username.

If this does not works, here is the more dangerous way. If I remember good, on Tiger is an application /Applications/Utilities/Netinfo Manager.app (or something like with Netino)

You should start it and check it. Unfortunately I'm not remembering what exactly you must do. One thing: when you change something, in the menu is something like "Restart Netinfo Server", and you must restart it, when you make changes.

**Warning: REALLY (really really!) be very careful. You can lock out yourself from the machine, and will must start OS in singeleuser mode to restore things - and probably will not get any help, because here are only few users with Tiger.**

I was thinking about this post and maybe would be better write nothing - because of the dangerous command. But, on the other side - if you do things carefully (google for Netinfo), you can easily done your problem.

Be careful - good luck. ;)

Comment: Have I been somehow unclear ? I guess so. let me clarify a point : Tiger has not the `dscl` command, but `nicl`, which is its ancestor.

Comment: but AFAIK have the NetInfo Manager... or no?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I don't even have the slightest begin of understanding of how it works.

Comment: ok, later will delete my answer - i only want point you to one app, with witch is possible do most of OS X specific config things (users, groups, mounts, sharing) etc - but it is removed from the Leopard, so i can't "navigate" you, what to do...