# Problem installing homebrew on tiger?

Tags: homebrew, macos

I haven't run into the permissions problem (yet) reported [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/how-do-i-install-homebrew-on-tiger). Using the curl  command [here](http://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger) I don't think it's necessary to do the staff group thing but am running into other problems. At first I ran into problems because the ruby 1.8.2 in /usr/bin didn't support the RUBY_PATCHLEVEL variable. I downloaded the ruby one-click installer (1.8.6) and moved it to /usr/bin and now I am getting this error when running 'brew install git':

```
no such file to load -- no brew-install.rb
```

(I tried installing newer ruby versions first but RVM now requires gcc 4.2 which is not present in the newest Xcode (2.5) that will run on tiger.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Tiger?

Comment: I was just about to ask them the same question until I saw your comment. Ruby is a tough cookie on all operating systems.